# How can I change the keyboard shortcut to accept inline suggestions only when inside snippets?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm wondering if it possible to change the key for accept inline suggestion only for when I am writing a snippet. I know it can be disabled fully when writing a snippet but I want it enabled and set to a key other than tab (like ctrl+tab). I like having it as tab normally so I am trying to avoid changing the keybind for all situations, but if there is no other option I will. I want this primarily for working with LaTeX workshop, so if there is a setting through that, that would be good too.

I have tried googling and browsing through the VS Code and LaTeX Workshop settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `isSnippetMode` [when clause context key](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#available-context-keys).

Ex.

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+n",
    "command": "acceptSelectedSuggestion",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && inSnippetMode"
}
```

To unbind the existing ones, find out which one exist by searching `acceptSelectedSuggestion` in the keyboard shortcut editor UI and then right click them and copy them, then paste them into the keybindings.json file and adjust the `"when"` clause to be `"when": "editorTextFocus && inSnippetMode"`, and the `"command"` to be `"-acceptSelectedSuggestion"`.